# # of Questions per day?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'd like to know how many questions a person is allowed to post per day.  Please include a link to the pertinent answer. I searched the site in vain for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* post as many questions per day as you want, until the site limits you. However, whether those questions will be *good* is another question entirely. Generally, if you post more than one question per day, it's almost certain that there wasn't much effort put into the questions. And in that case, they will likely not be well-received.

Comment: Another point to extend what Deusovi has said is that if you're churning out lots of little puzzles, you might think about incorporating them into a single larger puzzle. This can either be as a collection of puzzles, or by combining them into a larger puzzle/metapuzzle that brings it all together. I'd argue that taking that sort of approach is better for the site (less of a flood on the front page), better for the puzzle (nudges towards a higher quality/more interesting output), and better for you (a better, more interesting puzzle will generally be received more positively).

Comment: I agree with your point, but I think setting the bar at one question per day is going too far :-)

Comment: This looks like what you said to me on contacts but with clues instead of questions XD

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for rate limits. As Deusovi says, if you're bumping into the site limits then you should ask yourself if your questions are really as polished as they should be.

Comment: I think Wordster is more concerned not about hard limits enforced by the site software, but about snippy remarks from moderators about perhaps slowing down a bit. (There was one such from me the other day.)