# Is serial posting allowed?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Here are some questions posted on the main website by the [same user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47633/william-pennanti?tab=questions):

- [Guess the disney song from the initials number 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/71018/19989)
- [Guess the Disney song from the initials number 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/71023/19989)
- [Guess the disney song from the initials number 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/71027/19989)
- ...
- [Guess the Disney song from the initials number 9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/71041/19989)
- ....

All questions (about 10 on the last count) were posted in about 1 hour.
All of them are the same question with different "inputs". (not very high quality, but this may my just my personal opinion).
I have nothing against the questions or the user but this looks spammy to me.
Is this allowed, encouraged, frowned-upon?

Comment: See also [# of Questions per day?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437) ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting this many very-similar questions in such a short time period is definitely less-than-ideal.  Not only does it flood the recent-questions page, but it is also likely to garner downvotes as users get tired of seeing essentially the same question over and over.

It's recommended to spend the time to polish questions, and post them at longer intervals, both to give others a chance to have their questions seen, and to prevent users from getting fed up with repetitive questions.

Comment: Yup, agreed, this is not good behaviour and I have asked the user in question to stop doing it. And yes, it's likely that these will get a bunch of downvotes, which should also serve as a deterrent.

Comment: Would these "number-sign questions" benefit from being lumped together in one bigger question? If so, should posters be encouraged to do so rather than being asked outright to stop it? I seem to remember that posters of single cryptic clues were told to make larger posts. (That doesn't address the issue that most of these questions have been put together without effort and don't require much effort to solve.)

Comment: @MOehm I think combining them into one question is a good idea.  I intimated as much in my comment to the poster, recommending more comprehensive, polished questions.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth writing a general meta post to link to like we do with [Code puzzles - what (not) to do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)? (I'm aware that the answer to this is: Sure, write one. `:)`)